# Proxy configuration in powershell

Tags: proxy, powershell

I'm trying to install chocolatey on an windows behind a proxy:

```
@powershell -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted
```

In power shell I'm executing

```
$wc=new-object net.webclient;
$wc.Proxy=new-object system.net.WebProxy('<myproxy-ip>:8012',$true);
$wc.Proxy.Credentials = new-object system.net.NetworkCredential('<myusername>','<mypass>');
iex ($wc.DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'));
```

I get the following error

```
Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required."
At line:1 char:1
+ iex ($wc.DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'));
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
```

I use the same username/password that I must enter when I'm starting firefox/iexplorer (see the image). There are no default username/passwords configured for the proxy since I must always enter them.

[image]

---

More details (using Inspect Element in firefox on an Private Window)

**Response Headers**

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Length: 813
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Pragma: no-cache
Proxy-Authenticate: BASIC realm="PROXY_INTERNET"
Proxy-Connection: close
Set-Cookie: BCSI-CS-dfaeac52a135c7c0=2; Path=/
```

Comment: .Net credentials are not the same as a name and password you would type into a browser-based proxy authentication screen. Perhaps better describe the proxy and how you enter your UN/Password when using FF or IE.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I hope the image helps with identifying the type of proxy.

Comment: No, that's not enough. We'd need the HTTP response headers where the proxy is asking for authentication.

Comment: I added the response headers from browser. I don't know how I could "debug" or capture the response headers in powershell. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: The above example worked fine for me on Windows 7 behind an NTLM proxy :) thanks.

Answer (score 2):

See https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/wiki/Proxy-Settings-for-Chocolatey

In powershell define the function

```
function Create-Proxy($proxyHost,$proxyPort,$proxyUsername,$proxyPassword){
    #$proxy = [System.Net.WebRequest]::GetSystemWebProxy()
    $proxyUrl = $proxyHost+":"+$proxyPort;
    Write-Host "proxy url [$proxyUrl]";
    $proxy = New-Object System.Net.WebProxy($proxyUrl, $true);
    $passwd = ConvertTo-SecureString $proxyPassword -AsPlainText -Force; ## Website credentials
    $proxy.Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($proxyUsername, $passwd);
    return $proxy;
}
```

call it like

```
$wc=new-object net.webclient;
$wc.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
$wc.Proxy = Create-Proxy "<proxy-host>" "<proxy-port>" "<proxy-username>" "<proxy-clear-pass>"
$wc.DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1');
```

---

What I discovered is that the actual download worked, but the execution of the installer didn't since it used a custom constructed proxy.

So the `iex ($wc.DownloadString("https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1"));` fails because the bad proxy configuration inside the downloaded `install.ps1`

Answer (score 0):

Can't test it (don't have a similar Proxy available to me), so I actually have no idea if this will work, but here's something you can try:

```
$wc = new-object net.webclient;
$proxyUri = new-object system.uri("http://<myproxy-ip>:8012");
$wc.Proxy = new-object system.net.WebProxy($proxyUri, $true);
$cachedCredentials = new-object system.net.CredentialCache;
$netCredential = new-object system.net.NetworkCredential("<myusername>", "<mypass>");

$cachedCredentials.Add($proxyUri, "Basic", $netCredential);

$wc.Proxy.Credentials = $cachedCredentials.GetCredential($proxyUri, "Basic");

iex ($wc.DownloadString("https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1"));
```

The intention is to use a CredentialCache object to force the credentials into using "Basic" authentication mode.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this. Worked for me.
https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/Proxy-Settings-for-Chocolatey

Explicit Proxy Settings

**Chocolatey has explicit proxy support starting with 0.9.9.9.**

You can simply configure 1 or 3 settings and Chocolatey will use a proxy server. proxy is required and is the location and port of the proxy server. proxyUser and proxyPassword are optional. The values for user/password are only used for credentials when both are present.

```
choco config set proxy <locationandport>
choco config set proxyUser <username>
choco config set proxyPassword <passwordThatGetsEncryptedInFile>
```

**Example**

Running the following commands in 0.9.9.9:

```
choco config set proxy http://localhost:8888
choco config set proxyUser bob
choco config set proxyPassword 123Sup#rSecur3
```

Comment: This answer explains how to configure Chocolatey to use a proxy. The question asks how to *install* Chocolatey from behind a proxy. This answer will be useful after that, but it's not what the question was asking.